Kotlin multi platform project can't find iOS Framework
I'm following the documentation for adding a iOS framework without cocoapods to a KMM project,
And I'm getting this error when syncing the gradle, and of course is not integrating the framework, the error is
:shared:iosArm64Main: cinterop file: /Users/luis.garcia/Desktop/kmp-crash/shared/build/classes/kotlin/iosArm64/main/cinterop/shared-cinterop-luismafw.klib does not exist

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: /var/folders/h_/qb6wf4y90lz8c2blq8d3xbk80000gq/T/15310463132579371666.m:1:9: fatal error: module 'luismafw' not found
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.UtilsKt.ensureNoCompileErrors(Utils.kt:275)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.ModuleSupportKt.getModulesASTFiles(ModuleSupport.kt:83)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.ModuleSupportKt.getModulesInfo(ModuleSupport.kt:15)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.buildNativeLibrary(main.kt:564)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.processCLib(main.kt:307)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.processCLibSafe(main.kt:243)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.access$processCLibSafe(main.kt:1)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.Interop.interop(main.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.InteropCompilerKt.invokeInterop(InteropCompiler.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.mainImpl(main.kt:23)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.main(main.kt:45)

Here is how I got all setup
File structure:

the build.gradle.kts configuration:
listOf(
    iosX64(),
    iosArm64(),
    iosSimulatorArm64()
).forEach {

    it.compilations.getByName("main") {
        val luismafw by cinterops.creating {
            defFile("src/nativeInterop/cinterop/luismafw.def")
            compilerOpts(
                "-framework",
                "luismafw",
                "-F/Users/luis.garcia/Desktop/kmp-crash/iosApp/luismafw.framework"
            )
        }
    }
    it.binaries.framework {
        baseName = "shared"
        isStatic = true
    }

    it.binaries.all {
        linkerOpts(
            "-framework",
            "luismafw",
            "-F/Users/luis.garcia/Desktop/kmp-crash/iosApp/"
        )
    }
}

and the .def file content:

I except to use the ios framewerk in iosMain in the KMM project

The .def file you showed is missing the entry for headers =. See step 5 in the section on Add a library without CocoaPods.


Provide values for two mandatory properties:


headers describes which headers will be processed by cinterop.

package sets the name of the package these declarations should be put into.



For example:
headers = DateTools.h
package = DateTools

